# ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having this error - "ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl."
each time I try to run this query.
I know this issue is because a part of query is taking too long to respond.
I have tried to use Parallel Hints but did not work.
I do not have access to modify the timeout limit of the DB as well.
Can somebody have a solution to this problem at query level?

```sql
SELECT A.CR_ACCOUNT, B.CR_ACCOUNT FROM 
FCUBS.FTTB_CONTRACT_MASTER A
Inner JOIN FCUBS.FTTB_CONTRACT_MASTER B
ON A.CR_ACCOUNT = B.DR_ACCOUNT
AND A.DR_ACCOUNT = B.CR_ACCOUNT
AND A.PAYMENT_DETAILS2 = B.CONTRACT_REF_NO;
```

Comment: did you run an explain plan to see the costs?  How long does the query take to run outside of the application?  What language is the application in?

Comment: I am running this in oracle developer only where it keeps on running. I have modified the post with Explain Plan cost details

Answer (score 1):

"`ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation`" means your client told Oracle to abort the current call. Most likely you have a timeout setting in your client software configured. That's on *your client*, not the database. It is also possible that the DBAs have something that is doing an "`ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL`" on your session after an excessive runtime, but that's less common as it has to be manually written; it's not something most Oracle databases would do. Look at your client settings for at timeout.

As for your query runtime, first ensure you don't have a many-to-many join creating a partial Cartesian product. Test your join predicate this way:

```
SELECT CR_ACCOUNT, DR_ACCOUNT, PAYMENT_DETAILS2, COUNT(*) 
  FROM FCUBS.FTTB_CONTRACT_MASTER 
 GROUP BY CR_ACCOUNT, DR_ACCOUNT, PAYMENT_DETAILS2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

SELECT CR_ACCOUNT, DR_ACCOUNT, CONTRACT_REF_NO, COUNT(*) 
  FROM FCUBS.FTTB_CONTRACT_MASTER 
 GROUP BY CR_ACCOUNT, DR_ACCOUNT, CONTRACT_REF_NO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you get rows back from *both* those queries, you have a many-to-many join. Fix that by adding more join columns such that at least one side uses a set of join keys that are unique.

Lastly, if you don't have a many to many, it might be using indexes when it shouldn't be. You can try these hints:

```
SELECT /*+ FULL(a) FULL(b) USE_HASH(a b) PARALLEL(8) */ A.CR_ACCOUNT ...
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. I knew parallel hints may solve the issue but I think I was not using it correctly. Your syntax works now for me. Although the query is still slow but at least now I am getting results.
Thanks much for your help :)

Comment: Don't short-circuit the check for a many-to-many. Parallelism may be brute-force pushing yourself through problems that need to be addressed in code.

Comment: Yes, I am working to fine tune the indexes in the table to avoid using parallelism. thanks much for help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Indexes are the wrong thing to use here. You want full table scans and a hash join. You just need to be sure you don't have a many-to-many join here.